# How to compute smallest string in ArrayList using Comparator?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, comparator

I need to write a static method in a class MinTester that computes the "smallest" string 
from an ArrayList collection using a comparator object:

```
public static String min(ArrayList<String> list, Comparator<String> comp)
```

I cannot use the Collections class to compute the minimum.

Here is what I have so far.

```
public class MinTester
{

static String least;//This is static because it is being used in a static static context


public static String min(ArrayList<String> list, Comparator<String> comp)
{
   int min = 0;


  for( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ )
  {
    min = list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i++));
    if(min < 0)
    {
        least = list.get(i);
    }
    else if(min == 0)
    {
        least = list.get(i);
    }
    else
    {
    least = list.get(i++);
    }
  }
    return least;
}
}
```

I am using the min value because I read that the compareTo method returns negative, 0, or positive whether the first string is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

I am not getting any errors here from the method, So I try to test it in Main with this. 
I get this warning: "Accessing static method min"

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO code application logic here

    MinTester s = new MinTester();
    Comparator<String> comp = null;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("a");
    list.add("ab");
    list.add("abc");
    list.add("abcd");

   String a = s.min(list,comp);//Warning: Accessing static method min

    System.out.println(a);
}
```

My output from a = "abcd".  Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting "abcd" as the 'Min' string in the list?  I am thinking that my error is coming from my min() method, but I am not sure where inside it or why.

Comment: sort the element of the list on the basis of length,then acess the index 0 element i.e. smallest length

Comment: The logic in your loop does not make sense.

Comment: @NiksTyagi  Would that involving using the Collections class to sort it? If so, I am not allowed to use that.

Comment: @JoshM I explain why I try that logic underneath that code snippet

Comment: Why do you want to use a `Comparator`, if you just need the (one!) shortest element? Loop and compare would be simpler.

Comment: Why are you passing `Comparator` to the `min` method? You aren't using it anywhere.

Comment: @qqilihq I am required to use that signature, it was given to us. Cannot change it.

Comment: @Warlord I am required to use that signature, it was given to us. Cannot change it.

Comment: Then loop, use the `Comparator#compareTo()` in each iteration, to compare the current shortest string which you keep in a temporary variable to the string in the loop. If it's shorter, update the temporary variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to find the shortest `String` in an `ArrayList` without sorting it, you can simply traverse the list and check the `.length` attribute of every `String`, always keeping track of the shortest one.

```
String shortest = list.get(0);

for(String str : list) {
    if (str.length() < shortest.length()) {
        shortest = str;
    }
}
System.out.println("The shortest string: " + shortest);
```

**EDIT :**

You would use `Comparator` if you wanted to implement custom comparison of two strings. Comparing their length can be done in 1 line, so `Comparator` is really not necessary. If you absolutely need to use the `Comparator`, you would replace

```
if (str.length() < shortest.length())
```

by

```
if (comp.compare(str, shortest) < 0))
```

it's basically the same thing, except that you don't define the comparison by yourself but leave it up to the `Comparator` to decide, which `String` of the two is smaller. This way, if you wanted the way how the strings are compared in the future, you wouldn't have to rewrite the method, you would only supply a different `Comparator`.

Comment: This makes sense, but then why would I need to use comparator from the signature that was given to us that we cant change?

Answer (score 2):

**Using Streams and Comparator-**

```
Comparator<String> comparator = (str1, str2) -> str1.length() > str2.length() ? 1 : -1;
    String smallest = Arrays.stream(input)
            .sorted(comparator).findFirst().get();
```

Reference: [Find Shortest Length String](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/find-shortest-length-string-in-arraylist/)

Answer (score 2):

you can just use string lengths to compare and use min method of stream:

```java
stringSet.stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some pointer, using the `Comparator`, to get the idea. I'm not going to solve the whole problem, as this is obviously your homework (implement the `Comparator` for the `String` lengths, understand what `Comparator#compareTo(T, T)` returns, read the `Comparator` API):

```
public static String min(List<String> list, Comparator<String> comp) {
    String shortest = null;
    for (String current : list) {
        if (shortest == null) { // first iteration
            shortest = current;
            continue;
        }
        int comparisonResult = comp.compare(shortest, current);
        // TODO: your task; update shortest, depending on comparisonResult
    }
    return shortest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to do all of the work for you, so I will provide a solution in Scala:

```
object MinTest{

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val list: util.List[String] = List("a", "ab", "abc", "abcd")
    val m: String = min(list, (s1, s2) => s1.length - s2.length)
    println(m) //output is: a
  }

  def min(list: util.List[String], comp: (String, String) => Int): String = {
    if(list.isEmpty)
      return null
    var min = list(0)
    for(i <- 0 until list.size if comp(list(i), min) < 0)
      min = list(i)
    min
  }
}
```

Although this is a different language, the logic is still present. It's just your responsibility to convert it to Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple guys, cant you just create a hashmap from a list where the number in the hashmap is the length of the string then the value in the hashmap is the string that goes with that value...

Sort by the key, select item zero, then you have it , right?

What I'm saying is put all the strings in a list.. for each loop on that list, while doing so note the string in one column and the length of that string in the other "while you're there" , sort by the length, then pick the first string that goes with that length.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the length of the string element using the length method

```
e.g. list.get(0).length()
```

This should return the size of the string

Good Luck

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: I know its not the answer. Its just a tip that you could use throughout the process